# How to interpret "fishers of men" in Matthew 4:19 in light of contemporary analogies?

Tags: narrative-analysis, maetaphor

In the Bible, the sea is frequently mentioned both literally and metaphorically, serving different aspects and purposes in the biblical narratives. Here are some notable passages where the sea is a prominent element or used metaphorically:

Exodus 14 - The Crossing of the Red Sea: This is one of the most famous stories from the Old Testament, where Moses, by God's command, parts the Red Sea to allow the Israelites to escape from the Egyptian army.

Jonah 1 - Jonah and the Great Fish: In this story, Jonah is swallowed by a great fish (often depicted as a whale) in the sea after attempting to flee from the mission God gave him.

Matthew 14:22-33 - Jesus Walking on Water: In the New Testament, there's the account of Jesus walking on the waters of the Sea of Galilee, demonstrating His power over nature.

Revelation 21:1 - "Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth; for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and the sea was no more." In this verse, the sea is used metaphorically to represent chaos and separation, which are abolished in the vision of the new heaven and new earth.

Psalms 107:23-32 - This psalm describes sailors experiencing a mighty storm at sea, symbolizing times of tribulation and divine intervention to save them.

Job 38:8-11 - Here, God speaks to Job about the creation of the world, and the sea is described as if it were contained by gates and boundaries set by God.

In Matthew 4:19, Jesus tells His disciples, “Come, follow me, and I will send you out to fish for people.” This metaphor of fishing for people is intriguing, especially when considering the typical outcome for the fish - which is capture and, ultimately, death. How should we understand this metaphor in a Christian theological context?

Fishing as a Metaphor: In the ancient world, fishing was a common occupation, and the disciples would have been familiar with it. How does this background inform our understanding of being 'fishers of men'? Is there an implication of 'capturing' or 'rescuing' in this context?

Contemporary Analogies: I'm also interested in exploring contemporary analogies that might shed light on this metaphor. For example, in the TV series "American Gods," deities are depicted as being sustained by human worship, suggesting a metaphorical 'feeding' relationship. Could this idea of being 'fed' or 'nourished' by followers be relevant to understanding the role of disciples as 'fishers of men'?

Theological Implications: Lastly, from a theological perspective, what does it mean for individuals to be 'fished' by the apostles or modern-day evangelists? Is this metaphor meant to signify a transformation or a kind of 'spiritual death and rebirth'? For the fish being fished means death...

I'm looking for insights that can help bridge the ancient metaphor with modern understanding, possibly through contemporary analogies or theological interpretations that might resonate with today's readers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many analogies used in the NT are less than perfect according to modern understanding. The fate of the poor fish in the "fishers of men" analogy is one example. Strictly speaking people don't really want to be "fished," nor to they want to be "harvested." (Matthew 9:37) But once they have been gathered, in fact they are not eaten - they are saved from sin. Another imperfect analogy is the idea of people as sheep and ministers as pastors. People have free will and intellectual agency. Sheep are dumb animals who most people believe can be slaughtered or sheared without consultation. So that analogy too is imperfect.

The point of Jesus' calling his disciples in Mt. 4:19 is that they are to leave their professions and follow Jesus without worrying about how they are to earn their living or even who will provide for their families.

To put this in modern context, Jesus might be portrayed as finding his first disciples in a accounting office and saying:

> Shut down your Google-docs spreadsheets and follow me; I will make you networkers of people not data.

But the original is much more poetic.

Comment: brilliant, amusing analogy.

Answer (score 8):

To understand the metaphor, analogy, or parable in the scripture, it is better to keep it simple. Simon Peter was a fisherman whose job was to catch fish. When Jesus told him he would become 'a fisher of men', it meant that he had to change his focus from catching fish to catching people. The metaphor ends there, and there is no need to elaborate further by comparing the fate of fish and men.

Jesus called Simon Peter 'a fisher of men' because Peter himself was a fisherman. It did not involve any spiritual meaning. Later on, people who belong to the Lord are referred to as wheat, not fish.

Comment: Well answered, Vincent Wong. Jesus did not use the term ' to fish ' when he called  Levi, who had been a tax collector. He simply said: Follow me .

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan - Thank you!